# Hierarchical query with join. Performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, hierarchy, hierarchical

I am trying to form a query that fetch the details of subordinates under multiple level of supervisors. The hierarchy is as follows:
General manager- regional manager- district manager - supervisor - employee
My requirement is that, any manager in this hierarchy should be able to see the details of the employee at the bottom of the hierarchy.

So far I have tried the following options:

1: 102 seconds to execute

```
WITH w AS 
( select personId from assignments start with supervisorId = :inputId
Connect by prior personId = supervisorId)
Select columns FROM a,b
where a.column = b.column
And a.personId = w.personId;
```

2: 92 seconds

```
 Select columns FROM a,b
    where a.column = b.column
    And a.personId IN   ( select personId from assignments start with supervisorId = :inputId
    Connect by prior personId = supervisorId);
```

3:0.75 seconds[no data fetched]

```
WITH w AS ( select columns FROM a,b
        where a.column = b.column)
Select w.columns from w, assignments
Where t.personId = assignments.personId
Start with supervisorId = :inputId
Connect by prior personId = supervisorId.
```

In option 3, since join condition is executed first before connect by, that could be why it does not return any rows. Please note that when fetching data for a single employee, it takes less than a second to execute, ie by removing the hierarchical query part and the assignments table and giving personId of a single person.

So I am looking for an efficient solution to meet this requirement. Any method, even not including hierarchical queries are welcome.

Thanks,

Anoop

Comment: Guys, any way to improve performance of hierarchical queries in general?